# missing line numbers in windbg !clrstack

Tags: windbg

I analyzing a dump of an IIS application that I created with procdump.  I believe I have windbg setup correct and I can get a !clrstack with method names.  However, there are no line numbers.  Is this normal?  Is there a way o see line numbers.  What could I be missing.

Comment: You'll only see line numbers if you have this switched on (which it should be by default), and you have the pdbs without private symbols stripped, you can turn on line numbers using `.lines -e`

Comment: In most cases you have forgotten to let WinDbg find the correct symbol. But remember a fact that for .NET applications, line number is less useful, as you can often guess where the exception comes from.

Comment: Check the output of `lm` to see whether you have private PDB symbols.